# Is this bounded below by $2$ ?

Tags: calculus, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Having $x_2>\frac{1}{x_1}$, $y_2>\frac{1}{y_1}$, and $x_1, y_1>0$ can we bound $[(1-c)x_2+cy_2]^2+[(1-c)x_1+cy_1]^2$ below from $2$ ?

(We get $c$ from the formula of the mean value for functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

I thought to do something like:

\begin{align*}[(1-c)x_2+cy_2]^2+[(1-c)x_1+cy_1]^2&>\left [\frac{(1-c)}{x_1}+\frac{c}{y_1}\right ]^2+[(1-c)x_1+cy_1]^2\\ & >\left (\frac{1-c}{x_1}\right )^2+\left (\frac{c}{y_1}\right )^2+\left ((1-c)x_1\right )^2+\left (cy_1\right )^2 \\ & > \frac{(1-c)^2}{x_1^2}+\frac{c^2}{y_1^2}+(1-c)^2x_1^2+c^2y_1^2 \\ & >\frac{(1-c)^2}{x_1^2}+\frac{c^2}{y_1^2}\end{align*}

But I don't know if this helps.

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start like this
$$[(1-c)x_1+cy_1]^2+[(1-c)x_2+cy_2]^2\geq2[\frac{(1-c)x_1+cy_1+(1-c)x_2+cy_2}{2}]^2$$
You can come up with this inequality drawing a parabola, and connecting points on the parabola. It's known as Jensen's inequality. It's simple, and beautiful at the same time.

You can then do something like this, assuming that $c\in[0, 1]$.
$$ 2[\frac{(1-c)x_1+cy_1+(1-c)x_2+cy_2}{2}]^2>2[\frac{(1-c)(x_1+\frac{1}{x_1})+c(y_1+\frac{1}{y_1})}{2}]^2\geq 2[\frac{2(1-c)+2c}{2}]^2=2 $$
This comes from $x_2>\frac{1}{x_1}$ and $y_2>\frac{1}{y_1}$, and then from a fact that for $x>0$ we have:
$$\frac{1}{x}+x\geq 2$$
I realized i read wrong, and thought there was $x_2=\frac{1}{x_1}$, $y_2=\frac{1}{y_1}$, if i saw it was an inequality, i would of added more details.

Comment: So, do we not need the inequalities $x_2>\frac{1}{x_1}$ and $y_2>\frac{1}{y_1}$ ?

Comment: Also how we get the inequality $$2[\frac{(1-c)x_1+cy_1+(1-c)x_2+cy_2}{2}]^2\geq 2[\frac{2(1-c)+2c}{2}]^2$$ ?

Comment: I've added some more details

Comment: For the first inequality do we use the inequality $a^2+b^2\geq 2\left (\frac{a+b}{2}\right )^2$, or not?

Comment: Yes, it's this inequality. As i commented, it has a nice geometric intuition behind it.

Comment: We have that $$2\left (\frac{a+b}{2}\right )^2=\frac{a^2}{2}+ab+\frac{b^2}{2}$$ Why is this less than $a^2+b^2$ ?

Comment: If you want intuition, draw a parabola. If you want to check if it's really true, $2(\frac{a+b}{2})^2-(a^2+b^2) = -\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{2} = -\frac{(a-b)^2}{2} \leq 0$

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you very much!! :-)